# Determining an ODE with monotonically increasing solution and multiple steady states

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, biology, chemistry

I am trying to understand what kind of ODE or system of ODE would result in a monotonically increasing solution with multiple steady states. For lack of better terminology, a solution that increases in "steps", and moves to the next (higher) steady state after a previous (lower) steady state has been obtained.

For a single "step" that reaches a single steady state, a good candidate ODE can be the following:

$$A \rightleftharpoons B$$
$$ \frac{dB}{dT} = \theta_1A - \theta_2B$$

To achieve a step-like solution with multiple, increasing, steady states I have tried adding other steps to the ODE, turning it to a system of ODE such as:
$$A \rightleftharpoons B \rightleftharpoons C$$
$$ \frac{dB}{dT} = \theta_1A - \theta_2B - \theta_3B + \theta_4C $$
$$ \frac{dC}{dT} = \theta_3B - \theta_4C $$

with the hope that the sum of B and C would lead to the desired step-like response. Sadly, the value $B(t )+C(t)$ obtained from solving such system results in a single steady state.

What kind of differential equation could be resulting in the desired multi-step response?